# Is an MS in computer science helpful in improving programming skills?

Tags: masters, computer-science, code

I attained my bachelors degree in computer engineering in January 2014.  I was not a prolific programmer as an undergrad, instead focusing on my other coursework and in general completing my degree.  I am now paying the price for that.  I got a job after graduating that involved writing code, however I had a hard time understanding the programming tasks required.  Luckily I had senior coworkers who were very helpful.  Despite this I was fired after five months because I was unable to complete my tasks in a timely manner.

Since then I have begun working on my own (basic) projects such as library management and a chat engine.

After a few months I was able to get another programming job.  This time I was able to understand the tasks I was assigned, however I still struggled to complete them in a timely manner and my boss was growing quite frustrated with me.  I decided to leave the position after two weeks because of this.

I have continued to improve my programming skills since graduation, but I am still very slow at developing my programs and I rely heavily on Google.  I suspect that this is because I did very little programming as an undergraduate.  I do enjoy programming, and I regret not pursuing it more passionately then.

I have since considered applying to a masters program in computer science in order to improve my programming knowledge.  I'm not sure that this is the best route because I believe that most masters programs in computer science are more research oriented.  I believe that if I continue my studies and complete all my programming assignments I will be able to do well in industry.  I would appreciate any advice on deciding between a MS and an MBA so I can remedy the errors I made in the first two.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about industry oriented education.

Comment: Serious question: if you didn't enjoy programming in your undergrad, and you haven't found the motivation to learn since then, why do you actually want to make a career out of it?

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Questions about "Preparation for a non-academic career" *are* explicitly out of scope, per the [help/on-topic]. However, questions on "side-effects of an academic programme" seem defensible.

Comment: It doesn't help the credibility of a CS major that someone can graduate while being barely able to code. When I was going for my MS in Comp Sci, I made a point to program in C, which was the prevalent language back then, as much as possible. I got plenty of practice because no one in any of the teams I was on was any good, and I ended up doing all the project work - Better a shared A than a shared C, I suppose. Fact is, almost everything I know, except for theoretical Comp Sci, I learned outside of school. I do find the theoretical Comp Sci stuff valuable, as in extremely valuable, though.

Comment: So in short, you've spent years of your life in formal education, failed to gain basic skills necessary for your line of work, and have decided more formal education is the solution?  As a professional programmer this does not seem to be a particularly efficient or effective solution to the problem at hand.

Comment: Wow, you people are a very strange community where talking about how useful an education is outside academia is explicitly off-topic.  This meets all the sterotypes of academia hook, line and sinker.

Comment: @SteveSether StackExchange sites have an intentionally narrow field of topics that are considered to be on-topic for any one particular site. For Academia SE, that set of topics is, unsurprisingly, those about academia and is defined [here](http://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Well, not all Computer Science degrees are created equal. Some of them are focused on theoretical computer science. Their focus is on training actual theoretical computer science researchers, not on creating software engineers. As such, the actual programming requirements might be minimal. Theoretical computer science is to software engineering more or less what physics is to mechanical or electrical engineering. A physicist will have great understanding of concepts underlying ME or EE, but little practical experience designing stuff. Same with CompSci vs. software engineering.

Comment: CE != CS. CE is usually a lot more about hardware engineering than software engineering. (rest covered very well elsewhere).

Comment: @reirab Practical experience is something that you can acquire yourself, which is exactly what I did for myself. It would be pretty tough for somebody who is self-taught to use algorithms. I find theoretical Computer Science valuable because I can use this type of background to sort out whether a request is simply undoable. As far as I am concerned, it's good to know that some programming problems are simply not solvable.

Comment: @reirab For a question that's "off topic" this one has certainly attracted a lot of attention and answers.  It seems that your community disagrees with the narrow definition of what's on-topic when 7 answers have appeared with 23 upvotes to the highest rated answer, and the question itself has 20 upvotes.  Mayhaps your narrow definition doesn't reflect what the actual people in the community believe is worthy of discussion?

Comment: @VietnhiPhuvan Oh, I agree with you completely on that. I think a good computer science degree that is designed for software developers should have a good balance of theoretical computer science with the study of practical development issues and practical development experience. I was just contrasting that with a _pure_ theoretical computer science degree, which is usually designed more for people who want to be CS theorists, rather than software engineers. Again, the ME and EE analogy holds. ME's and EE's must master physics, but, unlike physicists, also need to study design issues.

Comment: **[Obligatory reading.](http://www.norvig.com/21-days.html)**

Answer (score 30):

Although having done a bachelor in computer engineering without doing any coding at all is highly unusual, learning to code is mainly a self-taught art. Even if you had been fully taught many programming languages during your undergraduate years, they might quickly become obsolete. On a perfect world an undergraduate degree on computer engineering must have given you the necessary theoretical base on databases, programming concepts, data structures and algorithms. Then it takes many / endless hours of coding to learn how to successfully apply those concepts on real-world software applications. So, regardless of doing a MSc or not, you must still code on your own "free" time, either on your little self-projects, on learning / self teaching new programming languages or participating on open-source projects and communities like Stack Overflow (SO).

The fact that you avoided coding on your undergraduate years is a bad sign though. Successful programmers are usually partly (or fully) geeks who enjoy installing / testing a new linux distribution every few months, hack their laptops to automate tasks, participate on SO by coding and solving other people's problem just for fun. Are you sure that coding is what you want to do for the rest of your life? Programming is really a hard and stressful work (as you saw on your first real jobs) and is very hard to enjoy it, if you do not have any real passion for it.

On answering your core question, most MSc programs I know, are mainly focused on particular aspects of IT science, such as databases, networks, electronic commerce etc and not on teaching programming. If your core motivation is learning how to program, I would suggest to follow (and pay for) some industry certifications (e.g. Oracle for Java and Oracle DB) and their respective structured courses. There is even multiple free educational material for those certifications, so you might even not need to pay for it. Still, to really learn coding you must spend hundreds of hours of actually coding and you should not simply expect to learn programming by studying at yet another course or getting a new degree.

Comment: I agree about the main point, in order to learn to program you have to do it. But please try not to propagate the myth about learning to program and learning programming languages, it is fundamentally two different things with no intrinsic correlation beyond that one learn the basics of programming along with a language. Once you are a good programmer picking up a new language is easy, and the basic programming skills will never be obsolete. Installing stuff is a chore, you have to do it, but you most certainly do not have to enjoy it.

Comment: As a geek and a programmer I must say I have never used Linux, I don't use a laptop and the only tasks I need to automate don't require any kind of hacking.

Comment: @eBusiness I don't see how would one learn to program without actually programming using some programming language. If your point is that no actual programming language should be used while learning, I... really disagree on that. Of course, theory behind the concepts is essential, but so is doing some actual coding.

Comment: @eis I am quite sure his point was, and I strongly agree on this, that "learning to programm" is not the same as "learning a programming language". I think you misunderstood the point, o course you have to use some programming language. But it is not simply learning the keywords and statements of  e.g. C++, but understanding the concept behind this. Once you do this (e.g. for OOP), it is quite easy to learn a new OOP language (of course, to master it, you will need lots of experience).

Comment: _learning to code is mainly a self-taught art_ — Perhaps. But learning to programm **well** is definitely not.

Comment: @dirkk yes, it's not the same. Though I don't see anything in the post claiming otherwise.

Comment: @JeffE On the contrary, like any other craft, learning to do programming well first and foremost requires practice, no one can teach you that.

Comment: I disagree with a lot of this.  Successful people don't waste time installing a bunch of software they don't need just for fun, and they don't waste time giving away free work on SO.

Comment: I agree with all of this answer except the second paragraph. It basically reads as "successful programmers do (all the things I do)". Successful programmers *program*, period. They do it often and improve their skills. This myth that you aren't a proper programmer if you've never compiled an OS from scratch, or tinkered with an Arduino, or some other ridiculous criterion, is actively harmful in its discouraging effect. No one would say "you can't be a successful carpenter if you don't spend time cutting down trees".

Comment: @ChrisHayes The second paragraph is not "successful successful programmers do (all the things I do)" but rather "successful programmers like to code / hack, install OSes" for fun and not always for profit.

Comment: @Alexandros I know programmers who are successful by most definitions who do *not* code for fun. It may not be the norm, but it's not required. And again you mention installing OSes, which is entirely orthogonal.

Comment: I, too, disagree with the current presentation of the second paragraph. I agree with the general idea that good software developers are usually (but not always) people who like tinkering around with software in their free time, but not necessarily in the specific ways mentioned here. Personally, I find installing new OS's regularly to be rather annoying. I might install one on a non-primary box to test it out, but I prefer to keep my primary boxes nice and stable. Few things are more annoying than trying to hunt down some kernel panic when you're trying to get stuff done.

Comment: [Meanwhile, trying to sort through a new Linux install that isn't working while typing this. - haha] Also relevant: http://xkcd.com/456/

Answer (score 25):

I feel like this whole question is a great example of someone taking a Bachelor's course on the assumption that it would open up career doors for them, without ever really considering or understanding how [little] said course related to their chosen career path.

No degree is going to magically make you a programmer or a software developer, surely not a research degree, and certainly not a *Computer Science* degree. "Computer Science" is a misnomer for courses that would be better called "*Computing* Science". It's not about developing software.

Taking a Bachelors course in Software Development/Engineering should have given you a great foundation, but it sounds like it may in reality have been more of a Computer Science course (a contradiction that is unfortunately rather common in the undergraduate academic world). Regardless, whether you took a real Engineering course, decide to go and take one *now* or just leave it be entirely, my advice is as follows:

**If you wish to improve your skills, take up more hobby projects and consider contributing an open-source repository.** It sounds like this is going to be a slow road so you should probably get an unrelated job to tide you over for the next few years until you have become a useful programmer.

Comment: It is not unreasonable to expect that a degree will certify if you are a competent developer. Should this guy have gotten a BS without knowing how to program is a different question...

Comment: @Mikhail: In my experience and that of many people I've spoken to, it is _entirely_ unreasonable to expect that a degree will certify you as a competent developer. Demonstrable real-world experience (be it commercial or otherwise) is the _only_ true mark of a competent developer. This is somewhat unique to our particular field, though, somehow. Of course competency _supplemented_ by a rigourous education is even more attractive for roles that may involve design and/or optimisation tasks.

Comment: LRiO is right.  You need actual experience in software development.  That means writing code, building, testing, DEBUGGING, [go back to building].

Comment: The question is "Is an MS in computer science helpful in improving programming skills?"… That's not the same as "Does it certify you as a good programer".

Comment: @bjb568: My answer talks about whether it will _make_ you a good programmer. Only in comments are we talking about certification.

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Your answer doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: @bjb568: _"No degree is going to magically make you a programmer or a software developer, surely not a research degree, and certainly not a Computer Science degree"_ answers the question directly, no? The entire purpose of this answer is to say "no, not usefully: do X, Y, Z instead".

Comment: I'd still say that "magically make you a programmer" != "helpful in improving programming skills"

Comment: Good answer, though it may be worth noting that most open  source repositories set a pretty high standard, beginners tend to get their patches rejected.

Comment: @eBusiness: That's a good point.

Comment: @bjb568: Okay, well, a hyperbolic equivalence was intended. :)

Comment: "Taking a Bachelors course in Software Development/Engineering should have"... he didn't.  Computer Engineering is not Software Engineering.

Comment: @BenVoigt: If you actually read the _whole_ answer you'll see that I agree.

Comment: Contributing to open-source software is not really fundamental to improving skills.  Many skilled developers have never contributed to any open-source software.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: No, you're suggesting that Computer Engineering is really algorithm engineering (because CS is algorithm science), and that isn't true either.  His course was Computer Engineering which is primarily a *hardware* degree.

Comment: @BenVoigt is right. Computer Engineering (at least what we call 'Computer Engineering' for academic purposes in the U.S.) is basically a mix of somewhere between half and 3/4 of an electrical engineering degree and about the same portion of a Computer Science degree (it's more than half of each since there's already significant overlap between CS and EE degrees.) It's usually geared towards embedded systems engineers and the like.

Comment: @reirab: How does the following not fit that? _"a Bachelors course in Software Development/Engineering should have given you a great foundation, but it sounds like it may in reality have been more of a Computer Science course"_ FSVO "more of", granted - I don't use this term to mean actually >50%.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Sorry, I wasn't really intending to disagree with you, more just pointing out that Ben's right that CompEng is typically a hardware-focused degree, not a software-focused degree. You're absolutely right regarding the distinction between theoretical computer science and software dev/engineering degrees, though. And, unfortunately, both are commonly just called "Computer Science," even though it's really a misnomer in the case of a degree focused on software development/engineering. CompEng isn't really either of those, though.

Comment: @reirab: Fair enough

Answer (score 13):

Getting a masters COULD improve your programming skills, or not, depending on the work you do, and the use you make of it.  There's also a question of exactly what kind of programmer you want to be, because all programmers/programming jobs are not alike.  Working on business-oriented software development, perhaps as a member of a large team, is quite a different experience from using programming as a tool in basic/applied research, where you may be one of a few (or the only) real programmer tasked with translating the ideas of non-programmer scientists into code.

I have to agree with others, though, that becoming a reasonably good programmer takes practice.  It's a lot like any physical sport: you can study the theory all you want, but unless you actually get out and DO it - and push yourself in the doing - you will never be good at it.  That means not just following a recipe (I'm almost tempted to say 'design pattern' :-)) to code something once and turn it in, but taking it apart and learning how & why it works, and perhaps more importantly, why it fails.  (Debugging is a highly underrated skill.)

I really think you should have gotten at least a start on this as an undergrad.  If your teachers didn't try to force you to, IMHO they shortchanged you.

Comment: Agreed.  It will depend a lot on the program/work done.  I had very few programming assignments in my MS program and they usually had very little applicability to my day job writing code in a generic business environment.

Comment: @RobP. In general, an M.S. in Computer Science isn't really supposed to be particularly relevant to writing generic business software. Graduate school in science and engineering is usually focused on preparing you for performing research or similarly specialized work. Regarding this answer, it really depends on the program. Software is not usually the primary focus of CompEng programs and software development isn't even always the focus of CompSci programs. Theoretical computer scientists, for instance, don't necessarily need much software development experience.

Comment: @reirab - Completely agreed.

Comment: +1 for mentioning that debugging is a highly underrated skill (along with all the other valuable insights).

Answer (score 8):

A masters degree in computer science will not increase your programming knowledge much, if at all. I earned both a bachelor and master degree in computer science. I did some programming for my bachelors degree, but very little for my masters degree. To my surprise, my masters degree was mostly a higher-level and less in-depth presentation of much of the same material covered in my bachelors degree (at completely different universities). (Lesson learned -- If I had to do it again, I would get my masters degree in a different field from my bachelors degree.)

Computer science coursework (for software development) focuses primarily on teaching the fundamental concepts of algorithms, database theory, graphics theory, etc. At the bachelor level, programming exercises are intended to help the student understand the theory and demonstrate a basic understanding. Degree programs do not provide in-depth training for any particular programming language or platform. Instead, they provide the fundamental concepts that are widely applicable in computer science. When I began professional work as a developer, I quickly discovered that my CS coursework left out many topics that were extremely relevant to the platform I was using and the type of development I was doing. There are so many languages and platforms that no CS degree could possibly cover them all. Many professional training books and courses offer in-depth training for specific platforms or types of work. But even those courses will not and can not cover everything you need.

I have worked with some developers who were great people, but only marginally competent at development. A competent developer (or a professional in any field) will have some amount of both **skill** and **talent**. **Skill** is a combination of training and experience. **Talent** is the in-born ability of certain people to intuitively learn concepts or skills in a field, and understand problems/scenarios in their field. For example, I took piano lessons as a child. While both I and my teacher tried hard to improve my skill, I really didn't have much talent. I finally gave up playing the piano when I realized that my lack of talent made skill acquisition very hard, and I would never acquire enough skill to compensate for my lack of talent and play well.

To put it bluntly, it sounds like you may not have a lot of talent for programming, and are trying to compensate with more skill (education). That may or may not succeed. I am not trying to be unkind, but to encourage you to take a hard look at your own talents. If you are not sure, ask a trusted colleague for their frank assessment. I certainly commend your desire to improve yourself professionally. I would encourage you to consider looking for another type of technical work that may be a better fit for the talents you do have. I have worked with colleagues who couldn't write decent code, but who had great customer service skills, a knack for regulatory intricacies, or an amazing understanding of reporting details. With your drive to improve, there is a position out there that is a good fit for you.

Comment: _To put it bluntly, it sounds like you may not have a lot of talent for programming_ — Downvoted. Programming is absolutley _not_ a skill that you can do well from mere talent, despite the nearly universal Dunning-Kruger effect that makes poor programmers to think otherwise. OP admitted that he didn't have enough experience; extrapolating anything about his innate ability is uncalled for.

Comment: @JeffE: I disagree, at least if I understood you.  I think there is a talent for programming, just as there is a talent for music.  From my own experience, learning programming was almost like being able to speak in my native tongue after living in a foreign land.  On the other hand, I have no real talent for music, and am still at best a mediocre musician despite probably thousands of hours of practice.  I think to be really good at anything takes both a native talent and a great deal of dedicated practice.

Comment: It's dangerous to equate Computer Science with Computer Engineering the way your first sentence does (and the first sentence in your second paragraph goes beyond dangerous to flatly wrong).  Computer Engineering is not the engineering counterpart to CS -- Software Engineering is.  Computer Engineering is scarcely distinguishable from "Electrical Engineering with Digital Electronics emphasis".

Comment: I didn't say talent doesn't exist; I said it wasn't enough. People don't become professional musicians through talent alone, either. Conversely, the fact that someone can't play the piano well (by professional standards) does _not_ imply that they don't have talent.

Comment: `"To my surprise, my masters degree was mostly a higher-level and less in-depth presentation of much of the same material covered in my bachelors degree."` That is very surprising, indeed. And, frankly, that's not how it's supposed to work. That was not at all my M.S. in CompSci experience. It's supposed to be quite the opposite: much more depth, but not as much breadth, as the undergrad degree. Graduate degrees (MBA and MEd aside) are supposed to be specialized degrees. It's not uncommon to be among the world's experts on some very narrow subject upon earning your M.S. (or, especially, Ph.D.)

Comment: @BenVoigt: I agree that Computer Engineering and Computer Science are separate fields. The first is focused on hardware, and the second on software. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @JeffE: I fully agree that talent alone does not make a good programmer, and skill is required and mostly self-taught. I have worked with people who loved to write software, but were not particularly good at it. I have also met highly talented people who eschewed hard work (and by extension, skill acquisition), and thus were also not particularly good in their field.

Comment: @JeffE: The OP recognizes that his skills are insufficient, and other answers have addressed skill acquisition very well. I disagree that "extrapolating anything about his innate ability is uncalled for". OP stated, _I am still very slow at developing my programs and I rely heavily on Google_. This is after 2 unsuccessful positions, help from coworkers, and personal side projects. This suggests (to me at least) that the OP would be well served to also consider his talents. I really would like the OP to have plenty of talent, and simply need more education and experience (skill).

Answer (score 6):

If your goal is only to improve programming skills, then doing an MS is just a waste of time and money. If you find it difficult to learn programming by yourself, you can take a free online programming courses in [Coursera](https://www.coursera.org/) or [Udacity](https://www.udacity.com/). There are plenty of them, for example:

https://www.coursera.org/course/interactivepython
https://www.udacity.com/course/cs046
https://www.udacity.com/course/ud036

Note also that there are many career options for a BSc degree in CS that do not require much programming skills. For example:

- If you don't know how to code, but you know how to test other people's code, you can become a test engineer.
- If you can talk to customer and convert the discussions into UML diagrams, then you can be a Business Analyst.
- ...

Comment: I agree. Just because you have your BSc does ***not*** mean that an MS is the logical next step. Take a couple of programming courses. Maybe coding is not your thing; that way you will find out. I know brilliant science people who just can't grasp coding.

Comment: Even if coding _is_ your thing, I agree with the answer that a Master's may not be the logical next step.

Answer (score 1):

You need to frame your question more precisely.  What caused your productivity problems in your programming assignments?  Saying you were "too slow" isn't very enlightening.  Why were you too slow?  Did you make too many mistakes that had to be corrected?  Are you sure your slow coding was the main issue?  Why do you say so?  To answer this question, you would need to consult your more successful workmates.  What did they say?

If you were having problems completing assignments on time, did you seek help or mentoring from coworkers or supervisors?  If your employers knew your educational background (and why wouldn't they?), why did they hire you in the first place?  If they hired you knowing your weaknesses, did they offer extra help?  Jobs are not like academics.  Jobs are focused on getting the job done, no matter what.  Besides gaining an education, in school your knowledge and capabilities are constantly being evaluated.  The job is not about you.  For that reason, good managers will help their employees be successful.  It's to everybody's benefit.

Without knowing where you attended college, or where you worked, I can't evaluate your poor understanding of English grammar.  If you attended college in an English-speaking country, why don't you know the language better?  If you were working on an English-speaking job site, I'd say your inability to communicate effectively was a hindrance. I have to differ a bit with you and one previous commenter about the nature of education.  Education should not be confused with training.  While a form of education, the latter is quite narrow.  It consists of imparting the minimum knowledge and skills to perform some function, programming or nursing for examples.  There are broader skills that education in seemingly unrelated topics can teach you.  From education in the liberal arts and sciences, you learn how to recognize patterns, how to generalize your observations and frame them in more abstract but general ways so that you can apply them to seemingly unrelated problems.  You will learn basic logic and how to use it to critically evaluate data and arguments you encounter in work and life.  Writing and speaking exercises will compel you to express your thoughts clearly and logically.

How well did you perform when you took these courses?  What did your teachers say about your performance?  If a college level liberal arts education is your foundation, but you lack specialized training in computer science and coding, then pursuing a Master's degree could be a way to acquire that training.

Answer (score 0):

I am myself an undergraduate student of CS and believe me I have realised very early that programming is whats going to matter. i wont be solving Calculus questions in the office. The situation of yours is different but what my Discrete Mathematics teacher told me, might be of your use. He said that after graduating, do masters and if possible doctorate as it opens up your mind towards your field giving you a much more dynamic and wide point of view of your field. So thumbs up for master's degree.

Comment: This very much depends on what you want to do with a Comp Sci degree. If you want to do theoretical CompSci, Calculus (and, more so, proofs) might actually be more useful than programming. For software engineers, though, programming is more important (and software design is probably yet more important.) IMO, a good CS undergrad degree should give a good balance of these concerns. Regarding grad degrees, they're typically actually rather narrow, though you may get a broader perspective from hearing about (or, better yet, collaborating with) your peers' research.